# ReFS 3.7 support in Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2019, refs, windows-server-2022

I have a ReFS drive in a setting with a Windows Server 2022 host and WS 2019 guest.
I usually pass through the drive. During troubleshooting, the drive was mounted on the host.
It seems like it got auto-converted to ReFS v3.7, which seems not to be supported by WS 2019. I have to use the drive in the guest though, which just shows the partition as RAW.

Any way to fix this? E. G. downgrade ReFS version or something similar? Also any way to prevent that auto-upgrade in the future?

(I am forced to use ReFS by the backup software, DPM. I only had trouble with ReFS, though googling it, there seem to be few people having issues with it.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up:

1. mounting the ReFS disk on the host (WS2022), it was readable
2. mounting a new drive in the WS2019 guest (previously, I used USB drives, now I used a fixed disk to avoid problems when USB connection broke and device got easier connected to the host) and formatting it with the "old" ReFS version
3. copying the data with robocopy to the shared drive that is old ReFS, preserving permissions.

> robocopy E: \\newvm\d$ /Copyall /S /E /B /R:6 /W:1 /Log:C:\robocopy-log2.txt /NP /J

So far the theory and what I spent days on.

The /B is good to copy data in folders where one does not have permission (when one is local admin).

It never really worked though. It was a DPM backup volume and many of the .vhdx files had a much larger size when copied then they took up on disk. Seem to have been sparse/diff files and I never figured out how to preserve that. Target drive would have had to be 5-10x the original size.

Please say if someone knows a better solution! I have a feeling this will happen again.